# How can print input from flask-WTForm to html with SQLALCHEMY

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

> I follow tutorial [Flask-WTF](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982)
>
> Now my question is how can I display the input that user enter in contact.html, and display it in info.html
>   with SQLALCHEMY? I use form.populate_obj() but don't know it is working or not and this is the things that I've done so far
>   the forms.py is the same and I make changes in routs.py and add model.py and info.html

```
#this is routs.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, flash
from form import LoginForm 
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask (__name__)
app.secret_key = 'pegahpegah'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
form = LoginForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate()== True:
    newcontact = Contact(name=form.name,
                              email=form.email,
                              subject=form.subject,
                              message=form.message)
    try:
        db.session.add(newcontact)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Contact commited to database')
        return redirect(flask.url_for('info'))
   except:
        #Something went wrong when trying to add to the database.
        flash('Could not commit new contact') 
    else: #If the form does not have all fields that are required 
        flash('All fields are required.')
 return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

@app.route('/info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def info():
  form = LoginForm()
  contactinfo = Contact.query.first()
  #Populate the form
  form.name = contactinfo.name
  form.email = contactinfo.email
  form.subject = contactinfo.subject
  form.message = contactinfo.message
  #returns the html page, along with the form        
  return render_template('info.html', form=form)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

> form.py

```
 from flask.ext.wtf import Form
 from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, validators, ValidationError
 from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

 class LoginForm(Form):
     name = StringField("Name", [validators.Required("Please enter your name.")])
     email = StringField("Email", 
     [validators.Required("Please enter your email  address."),
     validators.Email("Please enter valid email address.")])
     subject = StringField("Subject", 
     [validators.Required("Please enter your subject.")])
     message = StringField("Message", 
     [validators.Required("Please enter your  message.")])
     submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

> model.py

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from routs import db


class Contact(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = "Contact"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subject = db.Column(db.String(50))
    message = db.Column(db.String(50))


   def __init__(self, name, email, subject, ):
       self.name = name
       self.email = email
       self.subject = subject
       self.message = message

   def __repr__(self):
       return '<ContactForm %r>' % (self.message)
```

> info.html

```
     {% extends "layout.html" %}
     {% block content %}
    <h2>show the info</h2>
      {% for entry in form %}
         <strong>name:</strong> {{ entry.name}} <br>
         <strong>email:</strong> {{ entry.email }} <br>
         <strong>subject</strong> {{ entry.subject }} <br>
         <strong>messaget</strong> {{ entry.message }} <br>
        <br>
       {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}
```

> contact.html

```
   {% extends "layout.html" %}
   {% block content %}
   <h2>Contact</h2>

   {% for message in form.name.errors %}
   <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
   {% endfor %}

   {% for message in form.email.errors %}
   <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
   {% endfor %}

   {% for message in form.subject.errors %}
   <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
   {% endfor %}

   {% for message in form.message.errors %}
    <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
   {% endfor %}

  <form action="{{url_for('contact')}}" method=post>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {{ form.name.label }}
    {{ form.name }}

    {{ form.email.label }}
    {{ form.email }}

    {{ form.subject.label }}
    {{ form.subject }}

    {{ form.message.label }}
    {{ form.message}}

    {{form.submit}}
  </form>  

 {% endblock %}
```

when I press submit and all the forms all valid nothing happen and it doesn't direct to info and no flash shows and if I try to open info.html AttributeError

AttributeError: type object 'LoginForm' has no attribute 'query'

Comment: Please correct the code I'm sure that I missing a lot....

Comment: Nobody will debug all this code for you, that's not what stackoverflow is about. Please clearly present an issue you are struggling with, not all the code, unless it's of particular interest to everyone that might read the question. You should define properly what it is that you're trying to achieve, and where it is that you're stuck. a

Comment: It seems to me that you need to get a basic understanding of your code. In your contacts you are not doing anything with the form, you should probably store it to the DB. In info you should read from the DB, populate the form with the info you receive and then show it to the user. And you should format your code before posting a question.

Comment: @Zyber @ GG_Python Thanx for your comments, I had a hard time for this code, I'll appreciate if u could help me out,I edit the code, I add comments to the parts That I think there would problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will hopefully give you an working approach. I've added comments that hopefully will make it clearer on what is happening.

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
   form = ContactForm()
   print('ContactForm created')
   if request.method == 'POST':
      print('Entered Post')
      if form.validate_on_submit:  #If the form contains all required fields
         print('Form validated')
         #Create a new contact and commit it to the db.
         newcontact = Contact(name=form.name.data,
                              email=form.email.data,
                              subject=form.subject.data,
                              message=form.message.data)
         try:
            print('Trying to add newcontact')
            db.session.add(newcontact)
            print('contact added')
            db.session.commit()
            print('contact commited')
            flash('Contact commited to database')
            return redirect(flask.url_for('info')) 
         except:
            print('Exception')
            #Something went wrong when trying to add to the database.
            flash('Could not commit new contact') 
      else: #If the form does not have all fields that are required 
         print('Entered else')
         flash('All fields are required.')
   print('Return')
   return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

 @app.route('/info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def info():
    form = ContactForm()
    #Fetch the first contact from db.
    contactinfo = Contact.query.first()
    #if you want to fetch a specific contact you need to specify it like this,
    #contactinfo = Contact.query.filter_by(name='somenamehere').first()

    #Populate the form
    form.name.data = contactinfo.name
    form.email.data = contactinfo.email
    form.subject.data = contactinfo.subject
    form.message.data = contactinfo.message
    #returns the html page, along with the form        
    return render_template('info.html', form=form)

{% extends "layout.html" %}
  {% block content %}
     <h2>show the info</h2>
        {% for entry in form %}
           <strong>name:</strong> {{ entry.name}} <br>
           <strong>email:</strong> {{ entry.email }} <br>
           <strong>subject</strong> {{ entry.subject }} <br>
           <strong>messaget</strong> {{ entry.message }} <br>
          <br>
        {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}

---forms.py--
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class ContactForm(Form):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    subject = StringField('subject', validators=[DataRequired()])
    message = StringField('message', validators=[DataRequired()])

--models.py--
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from routs import db

class Contact(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = "Contact"
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50))
   email = db.Column(db.String(50))
   subject = db.Column(db.String(50))
   message = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

In the html we will loop through the data that we get in form, and for each entry we will print the information. NOTE: In my example you will always extract the first contactinfo from the DB and will therefore always get the same contact, as well as only ONE contact.

Edit: 
In forms.py we have created a form which will be used in the contact page. The form defines the necessary fields and structure of the form.
In models.py we have defined a model, representing an contact-entry in the database. This means that you will have to have a table called Contact in your database.

Comment: I guess I should import Contact in routs.py otherwise it would be error NameError: global name 'Contact' is not defined But I imoorted like(from model import*) on the top of routs.py, But ImportError: cannot import name Contact So I put it after db = SQLAlchemy(app) again nothing work and if I try to open info.html error **bold** sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError

 @Zyber –

Comment: Finally, I could make database and connect table to database But Now still flash not working and it won't direct it to info.html and when I open info.html AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'form.name = contactinfo.name can u help please? @Zyber

Comment: When you try and open info.html, and you get your attribute error. This means that you are not getting anything from your db query, it can't find a contact in the database. I'm guessing it's because when you are trying to add the contact to your database (in contact.html) it is not succeeding. For your first error it's hard to tell what the problem is since you are not supplying any direct information. Try adding some prints to find out what's happening. We need to figure out which row that is causing the problem. Check my edited code @Pegasuss

Comment: Make sure you are using .data on the correct places, in both info and contacts. Compare to my code and make the changes needed to make it look like mine. If it doesn't work, please put your current code in your question. @Pegasuss